# Deep link to my app does not open from web app or email using expo and react navigation Deep Links

Tags: android, react-native, expo, deep-linking

I can't open my deep link: exp://127.0.0.1:19000/ from web or email but works if I use this command line on my VM:

adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/settings"

is there any possibility to make this deep link behave like an url, in order to be able to open it from web and mail ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you ever sort this? I am having the exact same issue but cannot figure it out

Comment: No, documentation was unclear when I was working on the app. Also, I didn't find useful resources to solve the problem. It's frustrating ...

Comment: from what I have found out, the issue is with Chromium based browsers, and a possible solution is to redirect to your app using a custom schema or webpage - not implemented myself yet, but I believe this is the correct route. As you say though, limited resources makes this very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

May be this is late answer but if helpful to someone.

Here are some steps to follow to add deep-links into your expo project.
Please follow this documentation to add data into your app.json file to configure you app from client end [Linking](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/)

Add assetlinks.json file for android / apple-app-site-association for ios in .well-known folder into you server-side so that when you open link in browser it can remember your app in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with the DuckDuckGo APK on my emulator.